# mIRC socket HTTPS 400 Bad Request on Dropbox API

Tags: dropbox-api, mirc

I want use mIRC to create a folder on Dropbot

But the echo always get this message:

```
400 Bad Request
The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port
```

I have no idea why it happens.
This is my code:

```
alias dropboxCreateFolder {
  sockclose dropboxCreateFolder
  sockopen dropboxCreateFolder api.dropboxapi.com 443
}

ON *:SOCKOPEN:dropboxCreateFolder: {
  if ($sockerr) { sockclose $sockname | halt }
  var %data = {"path":"/myfile/songs"}
  sockwrite -nt $sockname POST /2/files/create_folder HTTP/1.1
  sockwrite -nt $sockname Host: api.dropboxapi.com
  sockwrite -nt $sockname User-Agent: api-explorer-client
  sockwrite -nt $sockname Authorization: Bearer Access_Token
  sockwrite -nt $sockname Content-Type: application/json
  sockwrite -nt $sockname $crlf $+ %data
}

ON *:SOCKREAD:dropboxCreateFolder: {
  if ($sockerr) { sockclose $sockname | halt }
  else {
    var %sockreader | sockread %sockreader 
    echo -s %sockreader
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1- You're not using SSL. This is a dropbox API requirement.

2- You're not setting a Content-Length header, you should really do this when POSTing.

```
alias dropboxCreateFolder {
  sockclose dropboxCreateFolder
  sockopen -e dropboxCreateFolder api.dropboxapi.com 443
}

ON *:SOCKOPEN:dropboxCreateFolder: {
  if ($sockerr) { sockclose $sockname | halt }
  var %data = {"path":"/myfile/songs"}
  sockwrite -nt $sockname POST /2/files/create_folder HTTP/1.1
  sockwrite -nt $sockname Host: api.dropboxapi.com
  sockwrite -nt $sockname User-Agent: api-explorer-client
  sockwrite -nt $sockname Authorization: Bearer Access_Token
  sockwrite -nt $sockname Content-Type: application/json
  sockwrite -nt $sockname Content-Length: $len(%data)
  sockwrite -nt $sockname $crlf $+ %data
}

ON *:SOCKREAD:dropboxCreateFolder: {
  if ($sockerr) { sockclose $sockname | halt }
  else {
    var %sockreader | sockread %sockreader 
    echo -s %sockreader
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you showed tells you that you send a plain HTTP request to a HTTPS port. This means that api.dropboxapi.com expects SSL connections to be made on port 443, but you're attempting to create a non-SSL connection.

You need to specify the [`-e` switch](http://en.wikichip.org/wiki/mirc/commands/sockopen) in your sockopen command to create an SSL connection instead.

Comment: Now I add -e after sockopen, But it show this "Error in call to API function "files/create_folder": request body: could not decode input as JSONHTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request" Is my %data wrong?